# Rails "550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender [RO1PR80MB1382.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, outlook

I use devise and this error occurs when devise try to send email to confirm user's email.

Follow below my development.rb which

development.rb

```
  # Email
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'domain.com' }  
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'badoda.com'

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'outlook.office365.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => 'it@domain.com',
    :password             => 'password',
    :domain               => 'domain.com',
    :authentication       => :login,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with Office 365 SMTP relay configuration. Please follow the steps [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#configconnector) to configure SMTP properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does your MIME message specify the right Sender header?